# How to Convert Array of Object to Flatten Array of Object using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, vue.js

I Have Array of Data like this and i want to convert it to flatten of array that return new of array like new header and the data it self.

for example in the 1st of Object i have name that includes 3 data " title, first and last
i want to convert to flatten like

From :

```
{
    gender: 'male',
    name: {
      title: 'Mr',
      first: 'Zedeci',
      last: 'Santos',
    },
    location: {
      street: {
        number: 7996,
        name: 'Rua Dezessete ',
      },
      city: 'Porto Seguro',
      state: 'Rondônia',
      country: 'Brazil',
      postcode: 64607,
    },
    email: 'samale.santos@example.com',
  }
```

To

```
{
    gender: 'male',
    name_title: 'Mr',
    name_first: 'Zedeci',
    name_last: 'Santos',
    location_street_number: 7996,
    location_Street_name: 'Rua Dezessete ',
    location_city: 'Porto Seguro',
  },
```

The Source API : https://randomuser.me/api/?results=5

```js
const flattenJSON = (obj = {}, res = {}, extraKey = '') => {
  for (key in obj) {
    if (typeof obj[key] !== 'object') {
      res[extraKey + key] = obj[key]
    } else {
      flattenJSON(obj[key], res, `${extraKey}${key}.`)
    }
  }
  return res
}

const data = [{
  gender: 'male',
  name: {
    title: 'Mr',
    first: 'Zedeci',
    last: 'Santos',
  },
  location: {
    street: {
      number: 7996,
      name: 'Rua Dezessete ',
    },
    city: 'Porto Seguro',
    state: 'Rondônia',
    country: 'Brazil',
    postcode: 64607,
  },
  email: 'samale.santos@example.com',
}];
console.log(flattenJSON(data))
```

but i got there

```
{
  '0.gender': 'male',
  '0.name.title': 'Mr',
  '0.name.first': 'Zedeci',
  '0.name.last': 'Santos',
  '0.location.street.number': 7996,
  '0.location.street.name': 'Rua Dezessete ',
  '0.location.city': 'Porto Seguro',
  '0.location.state': 'Rondônia',
  '0.location.country': 'Brazil',
  '0.location.postcode': 64607,
  '0.email': 'samale.santos@example.com',
  '1.gender': 'male',
  '1.name.title': 'Mrs',
  '1.name.first': 'Zedeci',
  '1.name.last': 'Santos',
  '1.location.street.number': 7996,
  '1.location.street.name': 'Rua Dezessete ',
  '1.location.city': 'Porto Seguro',
  '1.location.state': 'Rondônia',
  '1.location.country': 'Brazil',
  '1.location.postcode': 64607,
  '1.email': 'samale.santos@example.com'
}
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried. SO isn't a free code writing service. The objective here is for you to post your attempts to solve your own issue and others help when they don't work as expected. See [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: It's not array of data instead it just a plain object.

Comment: @decpk i get the data from json data  https://randomuser.me/api/?results=5

Comment: @charlietfl i va been put my code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to flatten the array, instead of just the objects inside. You can very simple change that by using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and run your function against each item inside: `data.map(obj => flattenJSON(obj))`:

```js
const flattenJSON = (obj = {}, res = {}, extraKey = '') => {
  for (key in obj) {
    if (typeof obj[key] !== 'object') {
      res[extraKey + key] = obj[key]
    } else {
      flattenJSON(obj[key], res, `${extraKey}${key}.`)
    }
  }
  return res
}

const data = [{ gender: 'male', name: { title: 'Mr', first: 'Zedeci', last: 'Santos', }, location: { street: { number: 7996, name: 'Rua Dezessete ', }, city: 'Porto Seguro', state: 'Rondônia', country: 'Brazil', postcode: 64607, }, email: 'samale.santos@example.com', }];

console.log(data.map(obj => flattenJSON(obj)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the below.

```js
function FlatternObject(parentKey, data, finalObject)
{
    if (!finalObject)
        finalObject = {};

    var keys = Object.keys(data);

    keys.forEach(key => {
        let currKey = parentKey === '' ? key : `${parentKey}_${key}`;
        if (typeof data[key] === 'object')
            FlatternObject(currKey, data[key], finalObject);
        else
        {
            finalObject[currKey] = data[key];
        }
    });
    
    return finalObject;
}

var data = [{
    gender: 'male',
    name: {
      title: 'Mr',
      first: 'Zedeci',
      last: 'Santos',
    },
    location: {
      street: {
        number: 7996,
        name: 'Rua Dezessete ',
      },
      city: 'Porto Seguro',
      state: 'Rondônia',
      country: 'Brazil',
      postcode: 64607,
    },
    email: 'samale.santos@example.com',
  }];

console.log(data.map(x => FlatternObject('', x, null)))
```

Comment: yes, get it, i modified my question. how if the data would be an array of object ?